# Log4j RollingFileAppender writing to previously rolled files

Tags: log4j

I'm using log4j 2.17.1.

Log4j is rolling files daily but will sometimes write to files it has already rolled. In some cases it is going back several days.

Example:

- app.log.2022-01-03 has been overwritten with data from 2022-01-04.
- app.log.2022-01-04 has been overwritten with data from 2022-01-10.
- app.log.2022-01-11 has been overwritten with data from 2022-01-17.

Is there anything wrong with my configuration here? I just want it to roll everyday.

```
<Configuration>

  <Appenders>
    <RollingFile name="A1" append="true" fileName="/var/log/app/app.log">
      <PatternLayout
        pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss} [%t] %-5p %c %x %m%n" />
      <FilePattern>/var/log/app/app.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}</FilePattern>
      <Policies>
        <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
      </Policies>
    </RollingFile>
  </Appenders>

  <Loggers>

    <Root level="info">
      <AppenderRef ref="A1" />
    </Root>

  </Loggers>

</Configuration>
```

Comment: Can you exclude the possibility that other logging systems are writing to the same files?  Log4j 1.x `DailyRollingFileAppender` for example uses the same file pattern.

Comment: I can. This is a brand new filename we started using when we moved from log4j 1.x to log4j 2.x. I can also say that we have multiple apps with different filenames and I'm seeing this issue with them, too.

Answer (score 1):

I believe my issue was caused by multiple LoggerContexts attempting to write to the same RollingFileAppender.

I resolved this problem by following the steps in the Log4j Web Application usage:

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/webapp.html

I had several web applications deployed to a single JBoss instance. Each app had their own copy of the log4j jars. I moved the log4j jars out of the wars and into a JBoss module to get them into the server classloader.

Then I followed the directions on the Logging Separation page:

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/logsep.html

and I configured a single LoggerContext for JBoss:

> Place the logging jars in the container's classpath and set the system property log4j2.contextSelector to org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.BasicContextSelector. This will create a single LoggerContext using a single configuration that will be shared across all applications.